# Ubuntu display gone after reboot

Tags: drivers, 20.04, graphics

I am a newbie to Ubuntu. I was working and suddenly got stuck then I restarted my PC but no display after rebooting. All hardware is working fine. Seems like the display driver has an issue. But now the problem is how to get terminal or anything on screen. It only shows no signal. I have tried alt+ctrl+f2, alt+ctrl+f6, and alt+ctrl+f7, but no success. I also tried it with a bootable usb of Windows but still same screen. Any help regarding this?

Comment: I guess it's more of an hardware issue rather than a software issue. Please Check your cables.

Comment: I have double checked cables, removed and plugged again but same issue again.

Comment: You've provided few details; we don't know if you're asking about Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Server?  or Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop.  If you restarted the machine; was it cleanly shutdown?  If it wasn't I'd boot *live* media & perform system checks, though if booting another OS (eg. windows) & screen doesn't work; I'd also agree it sounds like hardware issue.  I'd confirm hardware works using *live* media & not your installed system (ie. *Try Ubuntu* (or other OS) from thumb-drive but don't install)

Comment: 1- This question is for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop. 
2- Yes, it was stuck somewhere then I restarted and it was shut down cleanly. 

So should I try to boot the system with a bootable Ubuntu usb? Although I tried to boot it with windows usb but it did not work.

Comment: This is a Q&A site and not a forum, replies should be made via clarification to your heading.  By *clean* shutdown you mean you told the system to shutdown via a menu (ie. *clicked shutdown & confirmed & normal shutdown screens occurred*)? command? (ie. *you switched to text terminal & issues `shutdown -h now` etc causing normal shutdown*)or via SysRq commands direct to kernel (*bypassing any stuck UI/GUI*)?   or an *unclean* shutdown such as power-off button etc.  A *unclean* system (ie. not via mouse/command/keyboard command) is very different to a *clean* shutdown.

Comment: ah. Sorry, I misunderstood your question. as the system was stuck so I just did unclean shutdown and it was shut down by power-off button on CPU, not from terminal or GUI.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was a hardware issue, as one can see in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed ram and it worked. Previously, 3200 rams were working but I changed it with 2400 ones then it worked. It was an issue of clocking.